# Group By MySQL keep last value if null field

Tags: mysql

i have a table, where i need to sum some column values and group the results, but i need to see the last word value, if the word field is null.
sample table

```
| id| cod |  word | value |
| 1 |  1  | descr |     2 |
| 2 |  2  | texts |     3 |
| 3 |  1  | world |     5 |
| 4 |  1  | null  |     4 |
| 5 |  2  | null  |     4 |
```

select *, sum(value) as suma from table group by cod give this result

```
| cod |  word | suma  |
|  1  | null  |    11 | 
|  2  | null  |    7  |
```

but i need this result:

```
   | cod |  word  | suma |
   |  1  | world  |   11 |
   |  2  | texts  |   7  |
```

what is the correct mysql query to get this?

thanks

Comment: what have you tried, by `if the word field is null` have you looked at `coalesce()` for it.

Comment: You want to get specific this two rows or word != null??

Comment: how i can include te coalesce() function in th query?

Comment: your query is right actually :)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @oetoni `*` and `group by` together in the same query is NEVER going to be right.

Comment: @Strawberry, you are right...strangely as I build the same table for a test and executed ALEXANDER's query it produced that required result :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to be 100% sure use this:

```
SELECT cod, word, SUM(value) AS suma FROM test WHERE word IS NOT NULL GROUP BY cod
```

BUT:

[image]

i just tested it. This is the same table as yours, the same query as the one you mentioned.

Comment: thanks ,here only works with " word IS NOT NULL GROUP BY"